# Python: Use input from another command

Tags: python, input, command, pipe, cat

I am wondering how can I manage input from another command from a python script.

Example:

$ cat myfile.txt | my_python_script.py

How can my script manage the input stream from the cat command ? How Can I get an input from this piped commands ?

... Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4):

An easy and quite versatile way to accomplish this is to use the `fileinput` module.

```
import fileinput

for line in fileinput.input()
    # do things with line
```

This way you can both use the script in a pipeline (as you need to right now) or give one or more files to the script as a parameter (think `my_python_script.py input.txt input2.txt`).

Answer (score 1):

A good alternative to reading the standard input via `sys.stdin.readlines()`
: use the [pipes](http://docs.python.org/library/pipes.html) module.

> The pipes module defines a class to abstract the concept of a pipeline — a sequence of converters from one file to another. Because the module uses /bin/sh command lines, a POSIX or compatible shell for os.system() and os.popen() is required.

Here's a nice [tutorial](http://www.doughellmann.com/PyMOTW/pipes/).